# redactor editor paragraph tag inside ul->li->div is not supported

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor, redactor, octobercms

At first I was facing an issue that the rich text editor was not supporting div tags as by default it converts them into paragraph tags. Later I found a solution, which is to modify the **replaceDivs** attribute as **false** in the editor's js file. But now Im facing another one problem, when I include a paragraph tag inside a div element of a **list** parent tag, the **paragraph** tags are removed.

### Html Code in the Html edit section of the Editor

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <div><p> Hello world</p></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

after editing the code, when I preview

- Hello world

and after that if I edit again

### Html Code without paragarph tags in the Editor

```
ul>
    <li>
       <div>
             Hello world
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```